# Can anybody identify this office plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, office-gardening

Can somebody let me know the name of this plant? My office desk has inherited it and I would like to keep him alive :)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [Maranta arundinacea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maranta_arundinacea) which has been grown in low light so the white parts of the leaf are less obvious.  I base this on the the prominent leaf sheaths and the limited variegation.  They are similar to the [Aglaonemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aglaonema), commonly called Chinese Evergreen, but most aglos have more consistent variegation across the entire leaf.  The definitive way to identify this is to look in the soil.  Aglo's have white roots and [Maranta's have rhizomes](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Maranta%20arundinacea) which look like ginger.

This Maranta is also known as arrowroot, is edible and said to have uses as an herbal medicine.

This plant looks to be potted in the usual artificial soil mix with a high peat content. Maranta's prefer a consistently moist soil when they have the light to use the moisture.  I recommend moving it to a higher light area and thoroughly watering it on a regular basis.